# Invalid Argument on import code that works elsewhere

Tags: ms-access, vba

At a loss, I have an import module used to help my less technically proficient coworkers to import data to an access database for processing.  I use the following code for 8 difference text imports, they all work except for one.  I can manually import using the import specification so that is not the issue, I have triple checked the table and import spec name, also not the issue, can anyone tell me why access is throwing the error?

```
Function import_Headcount()
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim path As Variant

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM [tbl_Headcount]"


With fd
.AllowMultiSelect = False

    If .Show = -1 Then
    For Each path In .SelectedItems
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "National Headcount", "tbl_Headcount", path, False
    Next path
    Else
        MsgBox ("Import for Headcount cancelled")
        Exit Function
    End If
End With
Set fd = Nothing

db.Execute "qry_Update_Headcount_Fields"

DoCmd.SetWarnings True
MsgBox ("Import of Headcount complete")

End Function
```

It is throwing a "3001" error on the DoCmd.TransferText line, as I have said I have copy and pasted this small function 8 times with different tables and import specs and cannot see why this one is not working.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: How many characters is the `path` variable? Can you run just this single line from the debug window? It might help to rule out various factors...

Comment: Examine the value of *path* when `TransferText` fails.

Comment: Path is the same path I use for the 7 other extracts and is about 20 characters long, not really allowed to post for security reasons, it works for the other extracts.  I re-named this specific extract to "text.txt" to ensure there were no strange characters in the file name causing issues.  During debug, the path variable is what I expect it to be, and is the same as when I use the function for other files.

Comment: Does Access give you more useful information if you test the code after substituting `DoCmd.SetWarnings True` for `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`?

Comment: Hey HansUp, nope no difference in error messages.  I also tried re-formatting the table to all text data types (I was getting a type conversion error that deleted the header row value in one field) but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use square brackets in specification name?

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "[National Headcount]", "tbl_Headcount", path, False
```

Comment: Already tried re-naming the spec to "Headcount" as I suspected this might be the issue, it threw the same error.

Comment: What about your path? Could it be too long or contain same strange chars?

Comment: Works for the other files I import, tried importing from c:\ root directory and still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are on the right track on the troubleshooting side... Keep ruling out the variables until you can pinpoint the issue.

I would suggest installing [V-Tools](http://www.skrol29.com/us/vtools.php), a freeware Access add-in. This has a utility for managing/editing import specs. This would be the first tool I would reach for in debugging the import issue. It includes a number of other helpful tools, but for the project at hand, I think you will find the *Import/Export Specifications* form very helpful.

[image]

Here is a screen shot of an import spec we use on a daily basis:

[image]

As you can see, this utility exposes far more options than the built-in wizards when it comes to importing and exporting data.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but we are on a secure computer network with no ability to use any un-approved applications of any kind.  I will however keep this in mind for personal projects.